# Yandex Cloud SignatureDoesNotMatch C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, yandex-cloud, s3

Пытаюсь написать функцию генерирования подисанных url, но когда пытаюсь получить объект по сгенерированной ссылке получаю ошибку несоответствия сигнатуры.
Делаю по документации Яндекса: https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/storage/s3/signing-requests, https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/storage/concepts/pre-signed-urls

```
 public async Task<string> YCFileGetLink(string fileName, int lifeTime)
       {
           DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
           var dataKey = GetKeyedHash(_configuration["YandexObjectStorage:SecretKey"],
                 utcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
           var regionKey = GetKeyedHash(dataKey,"ru-central1");
           var serviceKey = GetKeyedHash(regionKey,"s3");
           var signinKey = GetKeyedHash(serviceKey,"aws4_request");
           var preparedCanonicalRequest =Utils.ToHex(GetSha256(GetCanonicalRequest(fileName,utcNow,lifeTime)));
           var stringForSign = String.Format(
               "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" + "\n" + "{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}" + "\n" + "{0}:yyyyMMdd" + "{1}" + "\n" + "{2}"
               , utcNow, "/ru-central1/s3/aws4_request", preparedCanonicalRequest);
           var signature = Utils.ToHex(GetKeyedHash( signinKey,stringForSign));

           var str = $"{(object) "https://storage.yandexcloud.net"}" 
                     + "/" + $"{(object) _configuration["YandexObjectStorage:Bucket"]}" + "/" 
                     + $"{(object) fileName}" + "?" 
                     + "X-Amz-Algorithm=" 
                     + $"{(object) "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"}" + "&" +
                     "X-Amz-Credential=" + $"{(object) _configuration["YandexObjectStorage:AccessKey"]}" + "%2F" +
                     $"{utcNow:yyyyMMdd}" + "%2F" + 
                     $"{(object) "ru-central1"}" + "%2F" + 
                     $"{(object) "s3"}" + "%2F" + 
                     $"{(object) "aws4_request"}" + 
                     "&" + "X-Amz-Date=" + 
                     $"{utcNow:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}" +
                     "&" + "X-Amz-Expires=" + 
                     $"{(object) lifeTime}" + "&" + "X-Amz-Signature=" +
                     $"{(object) signature}" + "&" + "X-Amz-SignedHeaders=" + 
                     $"{(object) "host"}";
           return str;
       }
        private  string GetCanonicalRequest(string fileName, DateTime utcNow, int expire)
        {
            var httpVerb = "GET";
            var canonicalUrl = _configuration["YandexObjectStorage:Bucket"]+"/"+fileName;
            var canonicalQueryString =  String.Format("X-Amz-Algorithm=" +
                                       "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" +
                                       "&X-Amz-Credential=" +
                                       "{0}"+"%2F20190801%2Fru-central1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request" +
                                       "&X-Amz-Date=" +
                                       "{1:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}" +
                                       "&X-Amz-Expires=" +
                                       "{2}" +
                                       "&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=" +
                                       "host",_configuration["YandexObjectStorage:AccessKey"],  utcNow, expire.ToString());
            var canonicalHeaders = "host:storage.yandexcloud.net";
            var signedHeaders = "host";

            return httpVerb + "\n" +
                   canonicalUrl + "\n" +
                   canonicalQueryString + "\n" +
                   canonicalHeaders + "\n" +
                   signedHeaders + "\n" +
                   "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD";
        }

        private byte[] GetSha256(string value)
        {
            HMACSHA256 hmacshA256 = new HMACSHA256();
            hmacshA256.Initialize();
            return hmacshA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
        }
        private byte[] GetKeyedHash(string key, string value) => GetKeyedHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), value);
        private byte[] GetKeyedHash(byte[] key, string value)
        {
            HMACSHA256 hmacshA256 = new HMACSHA256(key);
            hmacshA256.Initialize();
            return hmacshA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
        }
```

```
 private static class Utils
        {
            private const string ValidUrlCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";

            public static string UrlEncode(string data)
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (char ch in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
                {
                    if ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~".IndexOf(ch) != -1)
                        stringBuilder.Append(ch);
                    else
                        stringBuilder.Append("%").Append(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", (object) (int) ch));
                }
                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }

            public static string ToHex(byte[] data)
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; ++index)
                    stringBuilder.Append(data[index].ToString("x2", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Может кто подсказать что я делаю не так?